# Sequelize - Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to deploy a web-app and the database is a MySQL database that I'm connected to via Sequelize.

Generally I use PostgreSQL, but the web hosting uses MySQL with access via phpMyAdmin.

I have a api & db query that works locally and in Heroku (I assume because both uses PostgreSQL), but not with this web hosting probably because they use MySQL.

When I make the API call, I get this error below.

```
"sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ILIKE '%%' OR `Cocktail`.`description` ILIKE '%')' at line 1",
"sql": "SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `Cocktails` AS `Cocktail` WHERE (`Cocktail`.`name` ILIKE '%%' OR `Cocktail`.`description` ILIKE '%');"
```

Below is the query I'm making. It seems like this only works if I remove the `iLike`, the modulus operator `%`, and `Op.or`; which basically strips the search functionality.

I initially have `mysql2` installed, but I also added `mysql`, hoping it would somehow resolve this; but it didn't.

How would I resolve this issue? Sorry if a trivial issue.. I'm literally at a loss on how to proceed..

```
const paginator = async (req, res, limit) => {
  const { searchIngredients, searchTerm } = req.query;
  const ingredients =
    searchIngredients &&
    searchIngredients.split(',').map((ingredient) => `%${ingredient}%`);
  const { page } = req.query;
  if (!searchIngredients) {
    await Cocktail.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            name: {
              [Op.iLike]: `%${searchTerm || ''}%`,
            },
          },
          {
            description: {
              [Op.iLike]: `%${searchTerm || ''}%`,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }).then(async (data) => {
      const offset = limit * (page === undefined ? 1 - 1 : page - 1);
      await Cocktail.findAll({
        limit,
        offset,
        order: [[`createdAt`, 'DESC']],
        where: {
          [Op.or]: [
            {
              name: {
                [Op.iLike]: `%${searchTerm || ''}%`,
              },
            },
            {
              description: {
                [Op.iLike]: `%${searchTerm || ''}%`,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: Ingredient,
            as: 'ingredients',
            attributes: {
              exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'Cocktail_Ingredient'],
            },
          },
          {
            model: Step,
            as: 'steps',
            attributes: {
              exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'Cocktail_Step'],
            },
          },
        ],
      })
        .then((cocktails) => {
          return res.status(200).send({ count: data.count, limit, cocktails });
        })
        .catch(() => res.status(500).send({ message: 'error here too' }));
    });
```

EDIT:

Converted my `iLike` queries to be MySQL friendly using the below:

```
Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('name')), {
  [Op.like]: `%${searchTerm || ''}%`,
}),
```

Comment: Searching for `%%` is the same as finding everything. Why not just omit that term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In substitution of ILIKE, you can use LOWER() with LIKE to ignore case sensitivity.

Example: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE LOWER(productName) LIKE LOWER('%my search terms%');`

Comment: It's unlikely that a case sensitive collation is being used

Comment: thank you, I managed to use Sequelize functions to convert my queries to be MySQL friendly. ``Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('name'){[Op.like]: `%${searchTerm || ''}%`, }),``

Answer (score 0):

There is only [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) and no `ILIKE`.

[Case sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) is covered differently.

Comment: thank you, I'm turning all my `iLike` into `like` and using Sequelize functions to do the queries instead.